# Getting input from another window in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am having a little trouble with this project that I am working on. My project is this GUI application. In my test.py file, I call another file that contains instructions for another GUI window. This is where I am having trouble. In the test.py file, if you click run, a small window will appear. Click TEST in the small window. Then another window will appear that contains text fields if you enter numbers into the text fields for the window and then click enter. My IDE gets these error messages. It says that " ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' ' " My question is how do I fix this so that I do not get this error message? It is supposed to print the input that was entered into the window. I have two files, test.py, and model_objects.py. If you run model_objects.py by itself, it works perfectly. But when I try to import this file into test.py, it does not want to work right. This is programmed in Python. Also, my model_objects.py file is placed in a folder called util in the project. The values that I entered are floating-point values. I am having trouble with this. If you can help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my code:

model_objects.py (This is in a folder called util in the project.)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Style

import numpy as np

from util import InputData


class Harmonic_Oscillator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 0
        self.name = "Harmonic Oscillator"
        self.nparam = 2
        self.label = ["\u03BC", "k"]
        self.param = np.zeros(self.nparam, float)

    def set_param(self, param_list):
        for i in range(self.nparam):
            self.param[i] = param_list[i]
        return


class Morse_Oscillator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 1
        self.name = "Morse Oscillator"
        self.nparam = 3
        self.label = ["\u03BC", "De", "a"]
        self.param = np.zeros(self.nparam, float)

    def set_param(self, param_list):
        for i in range(self.nparam):
            self.param[i] = param_list[i]
        return


class Test_Oscillator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 2
        self.name = "Test Oscillator"
        self.nparam = 4
        self.mu = 0
        self.label = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
        self.param = np.zeros(self.nparam, float)

    def set_param(self, param_list):
        for i in range(self.nparam):
            self.param[i] = param_list[i]
        return


def model_prompt(potential_model):
    window1 = tk.Tk()
    style = Style()
    window1.title('PyFGH Parameters')
    box_length = 103
    for q in range(3):
        box_length = box_length + 33 * potential_model[q].nparam
    box_len_str = '300x' + str(box_length)
    window1.geometry(box_len_str)

    entries = []
    qvar = np.empty(3, dtype=list)
    for i in range(3):
        qvar[i] = []
    j = 0
    y = 5

    for q in range(3):
        for qparam in range(potential_model[q].nparam):
            qvar[q].append(tk.StringVar())

            ttk.Label(window1, text=potential_model[q].label[qparam] + " for Q:" + str(q + 1) + ":",
                      font=("Times New Roman", 15)).place(x=50, y=y)
            # set text variable as q1var[j] , each entry will have separate index in the list
            a1 = ttk.Entry(window1, textvariable=qvar[q][qparam], font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=140, y=y)

            j += 1
            y += 35

    def enter_button():
        for q in range(3):
            param_list = []
            for qparam in range(potential_model[q].nparam):
                param_list.append(qvar[q][qparam].get())
            potential_model[q].set_param(param_list)  # This is giving me error. Not working properly!!!

        for q in range(3):
            for qparam in range(potential_model[q].nparam):
                print(potential_model[q].param[qparam])

        InputData.output.items.model_data = potential_model
        print(InputData.output.items.model_data)
        window1.destroy()

    enter = tk.Button(window1, text='Enter', bd='20', bg='green', fg='white',
                      command=enter_button).place(x=110, y=y)

    window1.mainloop()


def output2():
    sections = []
    for i in range(3):
        if InputData.output.items.v[i] == "Model-Harmonic Oscillator":
            sections.append(Harmonic_Oscillator())
        elif InputData.output.items.v[i] == "Model-Morse Oscillator":
            sections.append(Harmonic_Oscillator())
        elif InputData.output.items.v[i] == "Model-Test Oscillator":
            sections.append(Harmonic_Oscillator())


#test = [Harmonic_Oscillator(), Morse_Oscillator(), Test_Oscillator()]
#model_prompt(test)
```

Here is another file called test.py

```
from util import InputData
from util import model_objects
from util import model_objects
from util.model_objects import Harmonic_Oscillator, Morse_Oscillator, Test_Oscillator, model_prompt
import tkinter as tk


def write_slogan():
    test = [Harmonic_Oscillator(), Morse_Oscillator(), Test_Oscillator()]
    model_prompt(test)


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="QUIT",
                   fg="red",
                   command=quit)
button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
slogan = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="TEST",
                   command=write_slogan)
slogan.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit esoteric, but the issue is this line in your `model_prompt` function:

```
qvar[q].append(tk.StringVar())
```

The quick fix would be:

```
qvar[q].append(tk.StringVar(window1))
```

The tkinter variable types' constructors accept an optional parameter - a handle to the window to which the associated entry widget is attached. If none is supplied, by default, it will pick the first `tk.Tk` window that was instantiated (in your case, that was `root` in `test.py`). The `StringVar`s will update themselves whenever the event queue of the bound window has cleared. Since you spawned a new `tk.Tk`, this interrupted your `root` event queue, and since your variables were bound to `root`, they did not update despite text being entered in the entries.

If you wanted to be super proper, you should look into `tk.Toplevel` or `tkinter.simpledialog` to spawn child windows. Your program should never have more than one `tk.Tk` window in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

i made a little example, i hope it matches yourr mainproblem. if you want to work with classes, in the most cases you need references.

```
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.test = Test(self) # test class import

        self.outputLbl = Label(self) # output Label 
        self.outputLbl.pack(side="top", fill="x", ipady=20)


class Test(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent # you can use this way to call between classes

        self._input = Entry(self.parent) 
        self._input.pack()
        self._input.bind("<Return>", self.outputMW)

    def outputMW(self, event):  # function, when pressing return it gives changes the text in your label
        var = self._input.get()
        self.parent.outputLbl.config(text=var)  # self.parent makes the reference to your other class


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.geometry("500x500")
    mw.mainloop()
```